# Hover animation to one item instead of all items for a menu

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a hover animation to my navigation items using Greensock animation platform. The animation works as I expect it to but it is applied to all the navigation items instead of just the item that is being hovered over. Below is a link to the code and  Codepen. Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
let $portfolioBtn = $('.portfolio-btn');
let $portfolioBtnUnderline = $('.portfolio-btn-underline');

$portfolioBtn.mouseover(function() {
  TweenMax.to($portfolioBtnUnderline, 0.5, {
    scaleX: 1,
    ease: Power4.easeInOut,
  })
});

$portfolioBtn.mouseleave(function() {
  TweenMax.to($portfolioBtnUnderline, 0.5, {
    scaleX: 0,
    ease: Power4.easeInOut,
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="active">
    <li>
      <a class="portfolio-btn" href="#">About</a>
      <div class="portfolio-btn-underline"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="portfolio-btn" href="#">Item 1</a>
      <div class="portfolio-btn-underline"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="portfolio-btn" href="#">Item 2</a>
      <div class="portfolio-btn-underline"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="portfolio-btn" href="">Item 3</a>
      <div class="portfolio-btn-underline"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="portfolio-btn" href="#">Contact</a>
      <div class="portfolio-btn-underline"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

https://codepen.io/rp20/pen/WdrwWP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
  <nav class="menu">
      <ul class="active">
        <li>
          <a class="portfolio-btn" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="portfolio-btn" href="#">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="portfolio-btn" href="#">Item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="portfolio-btn" href="">Item 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="portfolio-btn" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
.portfolio-btn {
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.portfolio-btn:hover {
  color: #000;
}
.portfolio-btn:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.portfolio-btn:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Oh yes, both solutions very helpful!

Comment: please click the tick mark if you've find it useful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have the same classname to all the buttons. Give each item a unique id and write mouseOver for individual ids. Give unique id for item 1, item 2, item 3... and add item-1.mouseleave, item2.mouseleave

Comment: This approach clutters up your js and html, and adding more menu items would require additional javascript. Getting the js event handlers to work with the same class would be much cleaner and more maintainable.

Comment: Since you've the same classname, hovering over one results in the selection of all elements with that classname. that is why all of them is getting animated.

Comment: Sure, but the correction you're suggesting is troublesome. What if the menu has 20 items. 200? That's a ton of unnecessary code. The power of classes is that we can do exactly what the op wants without needing to add a ton of ids by making a small adjustment to the code.

Comment: usually a view library such as react is used in that case

Comment: coming to think of it, you don't have to use javascript for this animation, it can be done in css using classname:hover. so it would be `portfolio-btn:hover{ css }`

Comment: Thanks. I considered using IDs but as Jason pointed out, ill be repeating a lot of code. I also tried it will pure CSS but not sure how to target .portfolio-btn-underline when you hover over .portfolio-btn

I read somewhere that you can use the $(this) keyword but struggling to implement.

Comment: You can use what @illiteratewriter said and target the following div using .portfolio-btn:hover + .portfolio-btn-underline { css }

Answer (score 0):

You are currently selecting all elements with the underline class, but you can select the element to animate based on the element that is hovered.

```
let $portfolioBtn = $('.portfolio-btn');

$portfolioBtn.mouseover(function(){

  let $portfolioBtnUnderline = $( this ).next( '.portfolio-btn-underline' );

  TweenMax.to($portfolioBtnUnderline, 0.5, {
    scaleX:1,
    ease: Power4.easeInOut,
  })
});

$portfolioBtn.mouseleave(function(){
  let $portfolioBtnUnderline = $( this ).next( '.portfolio-btn-underline' );

  TweenMax.to($portfolioBtnUnderline, 0.5, {
    scaleX:0,
    ease: Power4.easeInOut,
  })
});
```